# AndroidAnnotations: how to handle "activity is not registered in the manifest"

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-annotations, android-lint

When I use `@EActvity` in IntelliJ IDEA (v2016.2.4), the Code Inspection will issue a warning: e.g.

```
The '<activity> my.package.TestActivity' is not registered in the manifest
```

what is the recommended way of handling this situation?

1. the Lint help in IDEA indicates that we should make `TestActivity` abstract. This sounds reasonable, but when we do this, AndroidAnnotations will not generate the `TestActivity_` class anymore
2. another option is to add `@SuppressLint("Registered")` or `@SuppressLint("all")` to the `TestActivity` class, which has no effect (the warning is still there)
3. next option is to use `tools:ignore="all"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` , but this also has no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the [lint.xml](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings) file which can configure LINT suppressions. You can suppress this error like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="Registered" />
        <ignore regexp=".*TestActivity.*" />
    </issue>
</lint>
```

Comment: note: with this workaround IntelliJ will mark the `ignore` tag as error: see this issue: [“Element ignore is not allowed here”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685618/intellij-idea-element-ignore-is-not-allowed-here)